# Sites created by template have a broken Notebook link

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, site-template, onenote

I created a site template based on the default project page template, containing the default link to a OneNote Notebook for the project. To achieve this, I created a site called "Project 1" and used the "save site as template" option. After using the template for a new site called "Project 2", the link to the Notebook pointed me here:

> /sites/ ... /Project 2/_layouts/15/WopiFrame.aspx?sourcedoc=SiteAssets%2FNotebook%20f%C3%BCr%20Project%201&action=editnew

I am able to open this link, Sharepoint correctly creates a Notebook for the project, but the Notebook is called "Notebook for Project 1". Is there any way to edit my template so the Notebook uses the correct name, in this case "Notebook for Project 2"? Since my template is going to be refactored for every future project, I am not really keen on editing the link everytime a new project page is created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MC Technet support: You have to "**change the name of the notebook manually**".

My current workaround is to remove all the site notebooks with wrong file name by deactivating "Website notebook" in the website features, and reactivating it afterwards.

I also removed the notebook from the site template, so future sites only need to activate the feature.